# Google Weather API Conditions (plain text)

Tags: conditional-statements, weather, google-weather-api

I couldn't find ALL of the Google Weather API "conditions" in a simple, plain text format, so here it is for everyone if they can't find it either!

Comment: **The Google weather API was shut down in 2012** -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145820/google-weather-api-gone/35943521

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear
Sunny
Partly Sunny
Mostly Sunny
Scattered Thunderstorms
Showers
Scattered Showers
Rain and Snow
Overcast
Light Snow
Freezing Drizzle
Chance of Rain
Partly Cloudy
Mostly Cloudy
Chance of Storm
Rain
Chance of Snow
Cloudy
Mist
Storm
Thunderstorm
Chance of TStorm
Sleet
Snow
Icy
Dust
Fog
Smoke
Haze
Flurries
Light Rain
Snow Showers
Hail
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/806934

Comment: +1, but can you supply a link to where you found this (or, failing that, some kind of explanation)?